# TypeError: unsupported operand for +: 'dict' and 'str' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

Im writing a code in AWS Lambda. I need to read a json file and depends on what data need to capture different values from that json file. Please find the below code

```
    fileobj =s3.get_object(Bucket=srcbucname, Key=uploadfilename)
    filedata =fileobj["Body"].read().decode('utf-8')
    filejson = json.loads(filedata) # holds json file data
    print(filejson)
    dict1 = {"orders":["['items'][0]['ordernumber']","['items'][0]['name']"],"transaction":["['items'][0]['trans_id']"]}
    fileperson = filejson['items'][0]['name'] #Depends on what json file contains, need to pull desired details
    print(fileperson)
    key = dict1[fileperson]
    for i in key:
        j = i
        print(filejson+j)   # Here im getting [ERROR] TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'    

    print("Details provided")
```

Can you please provide me solution how to resolve [ERROR] TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str' and take output as per the scenario?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I actually want to print the value of filejson['items'][0]['name'] and filejson['items'][0]['ordernumber']. Here already the filejson holds the structured json data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `+` operator for `dict` and `str`. if you want to print both use comma separator.

```
print(filejson, j)
```

Or cast both to `str`:

```
print(f"{filejson} {j}")
```